# Protect single WordPress posts with .htacces and .htpasswd

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I'm lost and might need some guidance. Spent the last two days searching for a working solution, found plenty of posts, many of them pretty old, but nothing that would help.

For a client I'm running a WordPress site that has two functions: be an info portal and booking system AND display some info on 3 Android LCD screens running a Kiosk software.

The screens display 3 unique pages... Actually WordPress permalinks, that might be the source of the issue.

The code below is as close to working as I get it, in the sense that it prompts for user and password and also grants access when I'm proving the correct credentials.

```
# Infoscreen Protection
<FilesMatch "^(infoscreen-)[a-zA-Z]*$">
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/hostfolder/hostname/.htpasswd
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Satisfy any
Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

But it displays the page when I click on cancel, which is not ideal. I looked at this thread but couldn't get a working code out of it:

[htpasswd is bypassing when click cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399182/htpasswd-is-bypassing-when-click-cancel)

cPanel log says:

> AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/hostfolder/hostname/infoscreen-a

so the protection (and my regex) seems to work.

I found a post here (sorry, can't find it having too many stackoverflow pages in my history) that suggested to edit one line in the WordPress section of the .htaccess file to
`RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]` instead of `RewriteRule /index.php [L]` but that didn't seem to do anything except throwing error within other parts of the page like the booking system (I'm assuming as things are not where they're expected to be...). Also, although I'm prompted, credentials do not work and I'm prompted again...

Tried to wrap my FilesMatch inside of a `<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>` statement, but that only disabled the prompt.

Any suggestions on how to make this code work, I start not seeing the forest for the trees...

P.S. The path to the AuthUserFile is correct. Also, the page is a subdomain of my main site and is not inside the public_html folder.

Comment: Hm, this is a bit of a weird one. What do you have ErrorDocument set to, for 401 and 403 status codes? Those are not maybe set to the index.php of Wordpress again?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I don't have anything specific set for 401 and 403 status codes in my .htaccess (if that is the right place for those directives).

Comment: But I found this post on WordPress.org <https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-ignores-htaccess-errordocument-401/> that might relate to what @CBroe wrote. I will test and post results here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my question, but credit goes to CBroe who was suggesting that the solution was related to ErrorDocuments (Error Pages for those who, like me, have a hosting using cPanel).

After creating blank (in cPanel simply Edit and Save, no modifications needed) Error Pages for both 401 and 403 responses, the basic HTTP Authentication method started working.

Again, a big thank you to Cbroe for pointing me in the right direction! For an explanation as to why this is happening, see this [link on WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-ignores-htaccess-errordocument-401/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi not sure on the code above, but did you think about using the native Wordpress password protect feature for posts? Could that solve your issue?

Comment: Protecting posts via WP means the user will be shown a form to submit the post password via POST - probably not what they want to be doing from this Android kiosk application.

Comment: No, WP's password protect isn't working in that configuration. The kiosk software can do basic http authentication, but that's different from the WP function afaik. Also making it a private page doesn't work, as there would be a user logged in when a real customer needs to log in to make a booking.